# c# Datagridview cell not accepting currency format change

Tags: c#, datagridview, format, currency

I am trying to change the format of a cell in a datagridview using the following code.

```
        this.dataGridView[2, 1].ValueType = typeof(decimal);
        this.dataGridView[2, 1].Value = 500;
        this.dataGridView[2, 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
        this.dataGridView[2, 1].Style.Format = "c";
```

The colour of the cell changes but it doesnt not show in currency format.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Are you ensuring that the value assigned to  `.Value` is numeric? (i.e. not a string)

Comment: i thought that at first too so thats why i set the value type to decimal as shown above...

Answer (score 0):

In the examples I've seen, the "c" format is lowercased.  You may not need the "2" either.